# Shader linkage error/mismatch

Tags: directx, shader, hlsl, geometry-shader

I'm working on dynamic cubemap rendering. In particular, to render the cubemap I'm using a shader from the DirectX SDK sample "CubeMapGS". The shader seems correct, as you can see here:

```
SamplerState ss;
Texture2D tex;

cbuffer Constants
{
    float4x4 worldMat;
    float4x4 viewMats[6];
    float4x4 projMat;
};

struct VS_CUBEMAP_IN
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;
    float3 Normal : NORMAL;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct GS_CUBEMAP_IN
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION; // World position
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0; // Texture coord
};


struct PS_CUBEMAP_IN
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION; // Projection coord
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0; // Texture coord
    uint RTIndex : SV_RenderTargetArrayIndex;
};


GS_CUBEMAP_IN VShader(VS_CUBEMAP_IN input)
{
    GS_CUBEMAP_IN output = (GS_CUBEMAP_IN) 0.0f;

    // Compute world position
    output.Pos = mul(input.Pos, worldMat);

    // Propagate tex coord
    output.Tex = input.Tex;

    return output;
}

[maxvertexcount(18)]
void GShader(triangle GS_CUBEMAP_IN input[3], inout TriangleStream<PS_CUBEMAP_IN> CubeMapStream)
{
    for (int f = 0; f < 6; ++f)
    {
        // Compute screen coordinates
        PS_CUBEMAP_IN output;
        output.RTIndex = f;
        for (int v = 0; v < 3; v++)
        {
            output.Pos = mul(input[v].Pos, viewMats[f]);
            output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, projMat);
            output.Tex = input[v].Tex;
            CubeMapStream.Append(output);
        }
        CubeMapStream.RestartStrip();
    }
}


float4 PShader(PS_CUBEMAP_IN input) : SV_Target {
    return tex.Sample(ss, input.Tex);
}
```

However, it doesn't work. In fact, I receive the following DirectX error message:

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed: Vertex Shader - Geometry Shader linkage error: Signatures between stages are incompatible. Semantic 'SV_POSITION' is defined for mismatched hardware registers between the output stage and input stage. [ EXECUTION ERROR #343: DEVICE_SHADER_LINKAGE_REGISTERINDEX]
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed: Vertex Shader - Geometry Shader linkage error: Signatures between stages are incompatible. Semantic 'TEXCOORD' is defined for mismatched hardware registers between the output stage and input stage. [ EXECUTION ERROR #343: DEVICE_SHADER_LINKAGE_REGISTERINDEX]
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed: Geometry Shader - Pixel Shader linkage error: Signatures between stages are incompatible. Semantic 'TEXCOORD' is defined for mismatched hardware registers between the output stage and input stage. [ EXECUTION ERROR #343: DEVICE_SHADER_LINKAGE_REGISTERINDEX]
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed: Geometry Shader - Pixel Shader linkage error: Signatures between stages are incompatible. Semantic 'SV_POSITION' is defined for mismatched hardware registers between the output stage and input stage. [ EXECUTION ERROR #343: DEVICE_SHADER_LINKAGE_REGISTERINDEX]
```

The error message seems to indicate some kind of mismatch between the input arguments and the output values of the different Shader functions, however I can't really recognize this mismatch.

Any ideas or explanations in regards to this error?

Answer (score 1):

You do not read Pos in your pixel shader, because of that Tex get the register 0 while in the geometry shader output, it was register 1.

You can fix it like that, by putting output not read by the next stage at the end of the struct

```
struct PS_CUBEMAP_IN
{
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0; // Texture coord
    uint RTIndex : SV_RenderTargetArrayIndex;
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION; // Projection coord
};
```

Also, be careful with using the special `SV_POSITION` not from the last stage before the pixel shader, it behaves not the same between nvidia and AMD. just name it `POSDONTMESSWITHME` and because the vertex shader has to output it, put a fake one at the end of `GS_CUBEMAP_IN` and set it to 0.

As a piece of advice, geometry shader are a bad idea. Geometry expansion is pretty slow and not worth it for that kind of application, they are better at culling triangles, sadly they are the only stage to output the rt and viewport index without extensions.